# How to use AND operator when there are multiple IF conditions referring a table arguments in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an array formula in Excel that returns the difference between two columns if the two values are both non-zero numbers, otherwise it returns an empty string.

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/Details[Date1])- 1/(1/Details[Date2]),"")
```

I'm trying to change the formula so that instead of returning the difference, it returns

- `"Metrics Met"` if the difference `=0` or `=1`
- `"Metrics Not Met"` if the difference is `>1`
- `""` for everything else

I've been trying to combine IF with AND but haven't been able to get it to work.  This is my formula so far.

```
=IF(AND(IFERROR(1/(1/Details[Date1])-1/(1/Details[Date2]),"")>=0,
         IFERROR(1/(1/Details[Date1])-1/(1/Details[Date2]),"")<=1),
    "metrics met", 
    IF(IFERROR(1/(1/Details[Date1])-1/(1/Details[Date2]),"")>1,
      "metrics not met")
```

In the markdown table below,

- "Difference" in column C is what I would get with my old formula
- "Desired Output" is what I'm trying to get

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Date1** | **Date2** | **Difference** | **Desired Output** | **Note** |
| **2** | 6/14/2023 | 7/15/2023 | -31 |  |  |
| **3** | 6/14/2023 | 6/15/2023 | -1 |  |  |
| **4** | 7/15/2023 | 6/14/2023 | 31 | `"Metrics Not Met"` | `>1` |
| **5** | 6/15/2023 | 6/14/2023 | 1 | `"Metrics Met"` | `=1` |
| **6** | 6/15/2023 | 6/15/2023 | 0 | `"Metrics Met"` | `=0` |
| **7** |  | 6/15/2023 |  |  |  |
| **8** | 6/15/2023 |  |  |  |  |

In the image below, Column C shows what the output should be
[image]

Comment: [this may be useful](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-if-with-and-or-and-not-functions-d895f58c-b36c-419e-b1f2-5c193a236d97)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . Please edit your question and add a sample of how your data looks and what the formula tried to accomplish. Given that - as you say - your formula isn't a valid formula, it'd be difficult to make out of it what the real intent is.

Comment: Updated the question. Please let me know if your need more clarification

Comment: What should happen if `IFERROR( 1/(1/Details[Date1])- 1/(1/Details[Date2]),"")` is smaller than `0`? Note that `1/(1/Details[Date1])` is equal to `Details[Date1]`

Comment: I added an image that shows what is the expected output for the use cases. There are text values in both date fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Logic

For each pair of values, `d1` and `d2`, return

1. **`"Metrics Met"`** if:

   - `d1` ***and*** `d2` can be coerced to non-zero numbers;
   - ***and*** if `d1 >= d2`;
   - ***and***  if `d1-d2<=1`
2. Otherwise, **`"Metrics Not Met"`** if:

   - `d1` ***and*** `d2` can be coerced to non-zero numbers
3. **`""`** for everything else *(empty string)*

#### Formula

Nested [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) functions were used instead of using the [AND](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) function to insure the formula would continue to spill.

```
=IFERROR(
   IF(1/(1/Details[Date1])>=1/(1/Details[Date2]),
      IF(1/(1/Details[Date1])-1/(1/Details[Date2])<=1,
         "Metrics Met", "Metrics Not Met"), ""), "")
```

[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1802302/how-to-write-this-function-in-excel-when-referring-to-table-arguments-in-excel?noredirect=1#comment2825306_1802302.      Can you please help me with this question @Blind Spots

Comment: can you please answer this question : https://superuser.com/questions/1803521/how-to-write-multiple-if-conditions-using-table-arguments-in-excel.  ..