# How to write multiple IF conditions using table arguments in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Using references to table `Details`, how do I write this formula to subtract `Date2` from `Date1` if certain conditions are met:

**Calculation:** `=Date1-Date2` excluding weekends, or `""` if conditions are not met.

**Conditions:**

1. **`Type`**
   **Column 1**:  matches any of `{"new","old","contract"}`
2. **`letter`**
   **Column 2**:   `="yes"`
3. **`Business`**
   **Column 3**:   matches `"hospital"` anywhere
   `"myhospital2`, `"Great hospital"` , `"hospital #"` , `"hospital"` , etc.
4. **`Date1`**
   **Column 4**:  `=NOT(ISBLANK)`

I am not sure how to combine all these conditions in a formula. This is what I tried:

```
IF(OR(Details[Type:]="new")
IF(OR(Details[Type:]="old")
IF(OR(Details[Type:]="contract")
IF(AND( Details[Letter]="Yes"
IF(Details[Business]="Hospital"
Isnotblank(Date1)
```

This is my sample data with the expected output in `Result` column 5.

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Type** | **letter** | **Business** | **Date1** | **Date2** | **Result** |
| **2** | new | Yes | hospital | 7/21/2023 | 7/10/2023 | 11 |
| **3** | old | Yes | hospital |  | 6/25/2023 |  |
| **4** | contract | Yes | nursing | 8/10/2023 | 6/14/2023 |  |
| **5** | Referral | Yes | hospital | 7/10/2023 | 7/05/2023 |  |

[image]

Comments on `Result` column:

1. `F2=11`   Meets all conditions
2. `F3=""`   `Date1` is blank
3. `F4=""`   `Business` value invalid ("nursing")
4. `F5=""`   `Type` value invalid ("referral")

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not sure how combine all the conditions in a formula. I attached the image

Comment: Please also review the [IF function syntax](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)"  `IF(test, if_true, if_false)` as well as [AND function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/309330) `AND(expression1, [expression2, ...])` and the [OR function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306) `OR(expression1, [expression2, ...])`  to insure you are using correct syntax.  Your image is missing commas and ~6 right parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Formula 1

```
=IF(
   AND(
       OR(Details[@Type]="new",
          Details[@Type]="old",
          Details[@Type]="contract"),
       Details[@letter]="yes",
       IFERROR(FIND("hospital",Details[@Business]),),
       LEN(Details[@Date1])),
    NETWORKDAYS(Details[@Date2],Details[@Date1]), "")
```

**Function Support:**  [AND](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9)  [FIND](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-findb-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628)  [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)  [IFERROR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611)  [LEN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/len-lenb-functions-29236f94-cedc-429d-affd-b5e33d2c67cb)  [NETWORKDAYS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7)  [OR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/or-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0)

## Formula 2

```
=IF(
  ((Details[@Type]="new")+(Details[@Type]="old")+ 
   (Details[@Type]="contract"))*(Details[@letter]="yes")* 
   IFERROR(FIND("hospital",Details[@Business]),)*
   (Details[@Date1]>0),
  NETWORKDAYS(Details[@Date2],Details[@Date1]),"")
```

###### Explanation

- Where Excel expects a number `TRUE/FALSE` values are interpreted as `1/0`
- Likewise, where `TRUE/FALSE` is expected a number `<>0/0` will be accepted
- addition `+` is equivalent to `OR` and multiplication `*` to `AND`
- math order of operations applies (parentheses,  exponents, multiplication/division, addition/subtraction):
  `(1+0+0)*1*1*0=0` however `1+0+0*1*1*0=1`

| Type |  | letter |  | Business |  | Date1 |  | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| new **`(1+0+0)`** | ***** | Yes **`1`** | ***** | hospital# **`1`** | ***** | 7/21/2023 **`1`** | **=** | **✓** **`1`** |
| old **`(0+1+0)`** | ***** | Yes **`1`** | ***** | abc_hospital **`1`** | ***** | **`0`** | **=** | ✗ **`0`** |
| contract **`(0+0+1)`** | ***** | Yes **`1`** | ***** | nursing **`0`** | ***** | 8/10/2023 **`1`** | **=** | ✗ **`0`** |
| Referral **`(0+0+0)`** | ***** | Yes **`1`** | ***** | hospital#abc **`1`** | ***** | 7/10/2023 **`1`** | **=** | ✗ **`0`** |

## Formula 3

- cannot be placed within the table because tables don't support spilling
- will return the results for entire columns using a single formula
- Two key changes from **Formula 2**:

  1. `@` removed to make references to entire columns
  2. `[Date1]` and `[Date2]` are converted to arrays by adding zero because NETWORKDAYS doesn't support ranges.

```
=IF(
  ((Details[Type]="new")+(Details[Type]="old")+ 
   (Details[Type]="contract"))*(Details[letter]="yes")* 
    IFERROR(FIND("hospital",Details[Business]),)*
   (Details[Date1]>0),
  NETWORKDAYS(Details[Date2]+0,Details[Date1]+0),"")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77129554/in-excel-convert-the-unicode-text-to-number @ Blind Spots can you please respond to this question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77130152/how-to-get-the-distinct-count-by-name-and-date-in-excel Blind Spots this question is really important. Can you please respond to this. Thank you for your reply for the previous link. I will respond to that shortly.